# Switch autoCompleteTextView adapter between fragments

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, google-places-api

I'm developing a school app and I have to implement an `AutoCompleteTextView` to search `Google Places` predictions and users signed in the app's database, I'm getting the data I want and the adapters are working fine, but my problem is when I change from fragment 1 ( Where Google predictions autoCompleteTextView adapter is set up) to Fragment 3 for example (Where users autoCompleteTextView adapter should be set Up) isn't working if I try to search predictions first, I'm always getting the predictions adapter even on users fragment but if I search for users first it's working and if I search for places then, the adapter won't change..

I'm struggling with the last 2 days, anyone as a solution? Or know why this is happening ?

EDIT: 
My code for each adapter and the toolbar code is the same for each fragment

The toolbar:

```
 toolbar = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.toolbar_search);
            toolbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            autoCompleteTextView = toolbar.findViewById(R.id.auto_complete_text);
            autoCompleteTextView.setHint(getString(R.string.search_restaurant_text));

autoCompleteTextView.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                    googlePredictions(s.toString());
                }
            });
```

For users fragment:

```
List<String> usersNames = new ArrayList<>();
for (User users : users){
        usersNames.add(users.getUserName());
    }
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(), 
android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, usersNames);
autoCompleteTextView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

For Places fragment :

```
List<String> places = new ArrayList<>();
            for (AutocompletePrediction result : response.getAutocompletePredictions()){
                if (result.getPlaceTypes().toString().toLowerCase().contains("restaurant")) {
                    places.add(result.getPrimaryText(null) + "\n" + result.getSecondaryText(null));
                }
            }
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, places);
            autoCompleteTextView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: you have to show your code

Comment: Your question is not clear enough to understand

Comment: @Shaon i want to use 3 different adapters for each 3 different fragments in only one activity

Comment: You can do it. where is the problem

Comment: The problem is that i'm setting the adapters for the same autocompletetextview implemented in a toolbar, when i change fragment from bottom navigation view the adapter for that specific fragment doesn't set up, i'm always getting the adapter of the first fragment, i solved another way, i created  a new toolbar for the users fragment and it works but that is not the way i want to do it